# Linear and Unique types with mkPair

Tags: haskell, uniqueness-typing

I've been reading through this article here http://edsko.net/2017/01/08/linearity-in-haskell/ and the author mentions that one can construct a non-unique array with unique elements but that you can't extract them.

I.e.

```
mkPair :: 1:a -> 1:b -> ω:(1:a, 1:b) -- correct but useless
mkPair x y = (x, y)
```

but couldn't you read the elements once in the calling function? Maybe I'm missing something.

Also, although legal, this same function is illegal when looking at it from a linearity perspective. But I thought these were just 2 sides of the same coin, so the function would not change legality depending upon perspective.

Comment: By the way, I think you mixed up two examples. The function above is the one marked "incorrect" in the blog.

Comment: This function appears twice in the blog post; the first time with the comment "correct but useless" and the second with "incorrect". Either I've misunderstood what the author is trying to say about this function, or they've including the wrong function in the "correct but useless" case. As far as I can tell, this function is indeed incorrect - the most general type of `(,)` should be `n:a -> m:b -> (min n m):(n:a, m:b)` (as far as I understand, at least) which should reject the `mkPair` definition (since `ω /= min 1 1`).

Comment: @user2407038, the function appears twice: once under uniqueness types, the other under linear types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the author of the blog post means when he says that this is correct but useless. In [Clean](http://clean.cs.ru.nl), a language which has actually implemented uniqueness types, this is *not* allowed due to uniqueness propagation. You can read more about that in [section 9.2](https://cloogle.org/doc/#CleanRep.2.2_11.htm;jump=_Toc311798094) of the [language report](http://clean.cs.ru.nl/download/doc/CleanLangRep.2.2.pdf). There simply does not exist a type `ω:(1:a, 1:b)` (which is `(*a,*b)` in Clean syntax), because due to uniqueness propagation this actually is `1:(1:a, 1:b)` or `*(*a,*b)`.

This may be what the author is trying to express, but I find the post hard to read due to the lack of a theoretical framework.

Comment: Just so I'm understanding this: if you have a function mkPair and pass two unique types to it, the only result you can get it a unique pair? At that point the calling function could read the pair returned from mkPair exactly once, correct?

Comment: @tesserakt uniqueness is a property of types, not of functions. The type `ω:(1:a, 1:b)` simply does not exist, so the larger type `1:a -> 1:b -> ω:(1:a, 1:b)` also doesn't exist. You *could* define a function `1:a -> 1:b -> ω:(ω:a, ω:b)`, for instance `f _ _ = (undefined, undefined)`. You are of course not allowed to promote a unique type to a non-unique type (`f x y = (x,y)` with that same signature).

Comment: @tesserakt concretely,  "If you have a function and pass two unique types to it, the only result you can get is a unique pair" - I think you have the right idea, but type like `1:a -> 1:b -> 1:a` or `1:a -> 1:b -> Int` *are* possible of course. If you want to return a tuple of the arguments, it has to be unique and have unique elements.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `mkPair` is ill-typed (as the blog itself states), since its return type allows one to duplicate the resulting pair. So, any caller having unique values of types `a` and `b`, could make a pair, duplicate it, and take the four components (two from each pair), and obtain two values of type `a`, and two values of type `b`.

This would circumvent the linearity of `a` and `b`, so there must be no function having a type as the one of `mkPair` you show above.

Comment: So mkPair has to have the type 1:(1:a, 1:b), correct?

Comment: @tesserakt Yes, that should be its return type. We can't change the first 1 to ω.